# click sidebar link to change content in main div

Tags: php, jquery

I have spent about 4~5 hours looking through similar questions on this site and others, and can see that it is a favourite question: but am unable to find code specific to loading - say 50 different php files for viewing - into a main div. Lineal pagination is not an aim.

In a sidebar div, I have a list of html links to chapters of a book (separate php files).

Am using the id I give each Chapter/Topic/Subtopic as a selector for ajax jquery (am absolutely a beginner in all of this)! Below is my experiment with Section One.

```
<ul id="tocsub">
<li>
<h2>Section One</h2>
<ul>
<li><a href="#" id="ChI" name="ChI">Chapter I</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#" id="T1" name="T1">Topic 1</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#" id="Suba" name="Suba">Sub a</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="Subb" name="Subb">Sub b</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Topic 2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Chapter II</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Chapter III</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

I want to swap these chapters/etc within a main div on clicking any of the above links. So far I am using the script below to respond to the above links.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#ChI").click(function(){
    $("#posts").load("chapters/ChI.php");
  });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#T1").click(function(){
    $("#posts").load("chapters/T1.php");
  });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#Suba").click(function(){
    $("#posts").load("chapters/Suba.php");
  });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#Subb").click(function(){
    $("#posts").load("chapters/Subb.php");
  });
});
</script>
```

It seems to work up to this point.  I would like to know:

1) Is this heading towards an OK solution? Can the script be condensed?
2) Is it Ok to expand the script to include up to fifty different id's (Contents of the book)?

Warm regards in advance if you are able to help and thankyou for the replies below!

After a bit more research I am settling on:

```
sample link:
<li><a href="#ChI" id="ChI">Chapter I</a>

sample script:    
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#ChI").click(function(){$("#posts").load("chapters/ChI.php")});
  $("#T1").click(function(){$("#posts").load("chapters/T1.php")});
  $("#Suba").click(function(){$("#posts").load("chapters/Suba.php")});
  $("#Subb").click(function(){$("#posts").load("chapters/Subb.php")});
});
</script>
```

Comment: my preferred method is just to reload the page

Answer (score 2):

At this stage, where you evidently know yet know about `pagination`, you should be focusing on reloading the page with the new links.

Look up pagination.

Answer (score 1):

Well as I see it you have 4 Options:

- Link to each individual file (probably not the nicest)
- Reload the page with additional paramenters and load the content div with specific page you want
- Load all pages into different div(s) and hide the ones which should not be seen
- Refreshing the divs content via ajax

I am not sure if there is a prefered method here because, they all have their benefits and flaws.

- Loading each individual file, well I'd say its oldschool and you have to implement the pade layout into everyfile (except when using a header and footer file)
- Reloading the page ensures people without javascript may use the site
- All pages into different div(s) loads everything from the beginning (slower page load) but is faster when switching to a new page
- Refreshing the div(s) with ajax is probably the fastest solution (technically). The first pageopen is fastest and the individual pages shouldn't load to long.

Reloading the whole page or refreshing via ajax would be my personal prefered options. But I suppose it always comes up to the developer which he likes most.